# Multi website Subdomains Content Types

Tags: nodes, multi-sites

Is there a way to have a d7 multi-site build with the same database, header, footer, sidebar but when a sub-domain is called it will display a different content type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to set up multi site with the [domain access](http://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module and also [domain content type](http://drupal.org/project/domain_content_types)

Comment: You can also do something very similar when you combine Domain Access with Panels and use the same content types.