# Separate domain for specific content type

Tags: 7, domain-access, subsites

I haven't worked with multi-domain setups in the past so I did some research regarding the options for altering my website to accommodate for specific multi-domain needs.

My immediate need is to have a specific content type appear in links like:

```
http://my-content-type.my-website.com
```

According to what I've found so far, the [Subdomain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subdomain) module fits my use case exactly however, there are 4 things that keep me from installing it:

1. Very small user base (272 sites using it according to drupal.org)
2. It's a beta version since 2011 and the latest dev seems to be 4 months old
3. [It does not work with Global Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/node/774950) (which I happen to use in my site)
4. I will most likely need full sub-domain support in my website in the near future (different theme, custom user paths in separate domains etc).

Based on that, I came across the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module which seems to be the way to go for my future needs having the added benefit of a large user base, frequent maintenance releases and a stable version.

My question is the following:

Is there a way to minimally setup the Domain Access module to suit my needs for now (give me the option to setup a custom content type as a separate domain) and configure any advanced settings later? Is there any other solution that my research did not reveal?

Comment: I'm using https://www.drupal.org/project/content_theme (for a content type )for my website http://hannahaicah.com if you click gallery hanging system it will be entirely a new website layout and for the URL thing  I think you can do it without any module just simply redirect to subdomain.

Comment: Have you investigated this question/answer?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/multi-website-subdomains-content-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same choice to make 1 year ago and [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) was the best way to go.

To answer your questions:

- You can always configure what content is available on each domain (basically you will set the new subdomain and set your specific content type to be available only there)
- You can worry about advanced settings later; keep in mind now that almost all setting throughout the whole site can be differently set for each subdomain
- A good recommendation would be a multi site install like Karel suggested
- Another approach would be to just put some rewrite rules in your server, and have multiple themes set on each path which can contain a view that serves your content (this is pretty limited depending on what you want)

Comment: The Domain Access module comes with a lot of modules packed in and many, many more as available (including the domain_content_types module). Did you do a clean install in your case? Do you happen to remember which modules you enabled? Also, I have read that Domain Access requires node permissions to be rebuilt. Any links broke during the transition?

Comment: I had an existing Drupal installation, I had to install Domain Access and followed the usual procedure, like updating Drupal, updating database scheme.

I enabled all except Domain Strict, but I would recommend you enable all of it as Domain Strict also forces users to be assigned to a domain in order to view content on that domain; depending on what you are looking for here.

Nothing broke during the install, links were fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using the basic Drupal multisite setup using sites.php and a subdirectory for each site's settings file? This is the way to go if you want fully separated databases, but with a shared repository of modules and themes (and you can add site-specific ones too if you wanted).

Look at the file sites/example.sites.php, that should be enough to get your started.